# DNS Records working different on different computers

Tags: domains, dns

I have this kind of situation that is described below. Please don't ask me why. This is situation I need to work with, not change ;-)

I have three account/providers/servers

1. Domain registrar - codename Alpha
2. Old web server (with old website) and current mail server - codename Bravo
3. New web server (with new website) - codename Charlie

Before any of my actions there were only two of them (obviously - no Charlie). Alpha had domain registered and its DNS settings were set to Bravo's name servers. Everything (web, mail) was working fine, as expected.

Then I come in. I created new website, due various reasons migrated website hosting to Charlie. Upon website acceptance I go to Bravo and change DNS record A to point to Charlie's IP adress (to let mail be processed by Bravo).

And now be dragons. At first - I thought that this change (DNS record) shall be very quick as there is no need for propagation. I waited about 12 hours to see new website.

Customer also saw new website. Other tester as well. Then we went live and customer's readers started to report that they are still viewing old website, or some of them have some links broken on new website. I checked on various proxies and actually I see old version more often than new one.

How is that possible? Is it something that can be done or I have to wait? Maybe some action shall be performed on Bravo?

Oh, Bravo is on Parallels Plesk I believe, if that matters.

Comment: If you changed an A record, it can take quite a while to update throughout the Internet - anywhere from 24-72 hours - though generally no longer than 48. Cheers!!

Comment: It was done on friday so I thinks this period should be enough. What do you think?

Comment: This can also be a result of ISP DNS cache, browser cache, OS DNS resolver cache, cache servers at the ISP, and so on. This is not the norm, however, it does seem to happen enough.

Comment: Give the domain name involved and no codenames, then people would be able to correctly diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wait 48hrs for it to be fully moved around the world or tell them to clear their catch and it will force it to update.

OR

Move to google domain and you will not have this problem they even have a support team that will actually listen to you and fix your problem :)

Comment: Hi.  This was done on friday. That is why it is so weird.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to propagation, do wait for 48 hours and check again. If you see broken links on machines who have already visited the website it could be because of caching as well.

Try viewing your website on incognito instead of proxies

Comment: Hi.  This was done on friday. That is why it is so weird.

Comment: Are you using CDNs for the new/old server?

Comment: Nope. I don't. Plain http servers.

Comment: Can you post your DNS settings here?